# So what was so bad about my comment?

Tags: discussion

[What is not having a dominant foot called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248961/what-is-not-having-a-dominant-foot-called)

In response to the comment "@HotLicks actually, it's the 3rd most popular team sport in the US, after basketball and baseball", I replied "So, go ask FIFA", or something of that nature.  My comment was deleted, though Rajiv's response to my comment was not.

What was wrong with that comment?

Comment: There are current news items involving corruption at FIFA, and so maybe the comment was taken as inflammatory, rather than the more relevant checking with the particular sports authority on  among other things the terminology of the sport.

Comment: @Mitch - Yet my prior comment about FIFA's troubles was left unscathed.  Seems weird.

Comment: I don't see any prior comment about FIFA. Link?

Comment: @Mitch - The whole thread has been deleted since I posted this question.

Answer (score 7):

The comment "So, ask FIFA for the term" was flagged as "rude or offensive". It's not possible to see who flagged it.

That may seem innocuous, and if you read it with a smile, then it probably is. If you read it imagining a frown instead, it's a bit direct. While I probably wouldn't flag it, as a moderator I would delete it following the flag. At the very least it's not constructive. (It wasn't me who dealt with that flag, but I would have done the same thing.)

Note that moderators do not see context when dealing with comment flags. We see the comment and the flag. While it's possible to find the post and the context, it's not immediately available. All we get initially is just the comment and someone's opinion of it. If that opinion appears justified, the comment is deleted.

**Comments are ephemeral and should not be expected to last at all.** Conversations in comments are discouraged: they are intended only for seeking clarifications. Since that particular question and its comments has been brought up, I'll do a bit of clearing up. (Other heavily-commented questions will probably follow.)

Comment: Yet a later response came through with the soccer-specific terms the guy was looking for.

Comment: That didn't occur in the comments. Supplying answers as answers is encouraged.